# JQuery $.post not working on web server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a script using ajax to send a request to my php file. The php file should update a txt file. On my localhost the script works fine, but on webserver it doesn`t.

test html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

$(document).ready(function(){
for (i=1; i<=100; i++){
    $('#rate'+ i +'_').click(i, function(e){
    sendValue($(this).val(),e.data);
    });
}
});
function sendValue(str,str2){
$.post("/php/test.php",{ sendValue: str, sendValue2 : str2 },
    function(data){
    $('#display').html(data.returnValue);
    }, "json");
}        
</script>
</head>


<body>
<select id="rate1_" name="rate1">
<option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="rate2_" name="rate2">
<option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="rate3_" name="rate3">
<option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

test php

```
<?php 
if ((isset($_POST['sendValue'])) and (isset($_POST['sendValue2']))){
    $value = $_POST['sendValue']; 
    $value2 = $_POST['sendValue2']; 

    $array_rate[$value2]=$value;
    $i=0;
    $f1 = fopen('info.txt','r');
    while (!feof($f1)){
        $i=$i+1;
        $array_rate[$i]=fgets($f1);
    }
    $nr=$i;
    fclose($f1);

    $handle = fopen('info.txt','w');
    fclose($handle);

    for ($i=1; $i<=$nr; $i++){
        if ($i!=$value2){
        $array_boss[$i]=$array_rate[$i];
        }else{
        if($i!=$nr){
        $array_boss[$i]=$value."\n";
        }else{
        $array_boss[$i]=$value;
        }
        }
    }
    $handle2 = fopen('info.txt','a');
    for ($i=1; $i<=$nr; $i++){
        fwrite($handle2,$array_boss[$i]);
    }
    fclose($handle2);

    }
?>
```

on localhost my info.txt is updated but on server nothing...

Comment: Have you watched the request / response cycle using Firebug or some other console tool? You'll likely see errors there that will help you to solve.

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the console?

Comment: check write permissions

Comment: You should really use a class instead of looping through 100 ids

Answer (score 1):

Please check the directory on your web server using the ls -l or ll command and make sure there is a "rw" next to the text file you are modifying.

More information on file permissions:

- http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html
- http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions
- [Apache Webserver - How to write to dir/files with permissions set at 755 instead of 777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155194/apache-webserver-how-to-write-to-dir-files-with-permissions-set-at-755-instead)

as mentioned in the comments debugging is a good idea and can provide more information.

Chrome:
Right click and select 'inspect element' then click on 'console' this should display errors after running your code

Firefox:
install firebug http://getfirebug.com