# index.php automatically deleted after upload

Tags: php, apache

I'm working on a site in php on apache platform.
The problem is that every time I upload a file index.php in a subfolder (eg /admin) is deleted automatically

some clarifications:
if a load index.html does not delete it
only happens in the subfolders and not on the root

Help me please!

P.S. sorry for my english

Comment: P.P.S: sorry for not understanding the question !
please be clear at least...

Comment: Do you have the proper permissions to upload?

Comment: I have the correct permissions to upload files. The other files will load without any problems. All this happens only if loaded with the index.php file in a subfolder

Comment: @Shivanshu Srivastava: I upload the index.php file in the /admin and is automatically deleted when upoad is completed

Comment: by 'upload' do you mean you navigate to http://www.mydomain.com/admin/index.php ?

Comment: I intend to "upload" the file upload via ftp client.
if I try to navigate to the url mydomain.com/admin/index.php I get
404 Not Found The resource requested could not be found on this server!

Comment: what I can not understand is why this happens only with the index. php? and why it does not happen on the root folder?

Comment: How do you know that you've uploaded at all?

Answer (score 0):

I the first view it seems to be a permission issue in which there may be a permission set on the php files so that the FTP user's group will not be able to upload/overwrite it.

For more explanation about how to set permissions, you could check this answer-
 [Apache Webserver - How to write to dir/files with permissions set at 755 instead of 777](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155194/apache-webserver-how-to-write-to-dir-files-with-permissions-set-at-755-instead)

If your server is running linux there must be a **cron job** that checks condition for upload, on Windows there may be something similar to a script running **scheduled task**.
It may also happen that server is full and **resisting further upload**, but as you said it's not deleting index.html so skip this.